# Howto search and replace 3 jobs at once with regexp

Tags: regex

I'm using a program that's called ASR (Actual Search and Replace) which has some powerful features build in to search a text with regexps and replace it.

I'm using it a lot and I kind of scripted it into my workflow.

Problem is, I need to replace three searches to correct a configuration file (strip the "-" from only these three lines), this is all manual work and very time consuming.

The config file has got the following lines randomly through the file and they can occur multiple times with different names and numbers. They are always on one single line.

```
<id>filename-33</id>
<source>#filename-33</source>
<url>{filename-33}</url>
```

The desired output should be:

```
<id>filename33</id>
<source>#filename33</source>
<url>{filename33}</url>
```

Both "filename" as the number "33" can be anything (filename is always a name lowercase no special characters and the number is always a number from 0 to 1000).

I know howto find and replace all three lines with:

```
<source>#(.*)-     replace with      <source>#$1
<url>{(.*)-        replace with      <url>{$1
<id>(.*)-          replace with      <id>$1
```

But this has to be done in three separate runs.

My question is, is it possible to do a search and replace with just one single find line and one single replace line ?

Regards,

Arjan

Comment: Did you test the proposed solutions?

Comment: Yes, the solution works! I had to change some syntax to make it work with ASR to  (<source>#|<url>{|<id>)([^-]+)  and replace it with $1$2  the regex101.com site is also a very handy tool tip ! Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (using the `|` pipe operator) to create a single expression that will match all 3 patterns and create a single replacement.

Replacing this pattern:

```
(?:<source>(?=#)|<url>(?={)|<id>)([^-]+)-
```

with `$1$2` should result in the correct output.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3mP9/3

Analysis of the expression:

```
(             // begin capturing group
    <source># // find the opening <source> tag followed by a #
  | <url>{    //  ...or find the opening <url> tag followed by a {
  | <id>      // ...or find the opening <id> tag
)             // end capturing group
([^-]+)       // capture everything that is not a hyphen
-             // match and consume the hyphen
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it's working. The start tags are removed.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Oh sorry, of course they would be, updated. I over-complicated it

Comment: It also depends on the user's data size. My second versions runs using half the steps needed for your regex.

Comment: That works perfect for me ! You saved my day. That regex101.com is also a very handy tool, I'll remember that !

Comment: I did have to rewrite it a little bit to work with ASR final result is (<source>#|<url>{|<id>)([^-]+)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `^(<(?:id|source|url)>(#|\{)?\w+)-` and replacing it with `$1` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/tZ6yD5/1).

Comment: This will also match e.g. `<url>#filename-33</url>`

Comment: There is a possibility of that string to never show up. It depends on the user's actual data, because it can also be done using [this](https://regex101.com/r/tZ6yD5/2) which is simpler to understand.

Comment: True. I'd actually argue that (from the look of the data) some kind of DOM tool could be better, as you could then handle the data as what it appears to be (XML) and XPath for the target nodes and manipulate the data as data, rather than treating the whole thing as an string, but that may be overkill.

Comment: I'm using "Actual Search and Replace" in my workflow, it runs on windows and I have some custom manipulation search and replace tools that are using it. I'm bound to the regexp search and replace in ASR unfortunately. Otherwise I would have written a .xslt script to manipulate the data (you are right it is a xml config file).

Comment: @ Iulian Onofrei Jun 7 at 8:47     that will not work it matches to much, the rest of the config file contains lines with possible "-" in it that should not be changed.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave this answer here, though. Maybe it can help others.